# cómo implementar dataTable jquery en tabla llenada con ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena por medio de ajax.

```js
$(function() { $('#stat').load('ajax/todo.php'); });
```

```html
<table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>apellidos</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>apellidos</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody id="stat"></tbody>
</table>
```

En el archivo todo.php se encuentra los resultados de la tabla de esta manera

```js
foreach ($filas as $key)
 {
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $key['id'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $key['nombre'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $key['apellidos'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }  ?>
```

Quiero implementar la función dataTable de JQuery

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#tabla').DataTable();
        } );
```

Pero al agregar esta función, cuando esta cargando los datos manda un error `no data available in` después carga los datos, cuando intento buscar no arroja los resultados que debería.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `load()` es una funcion asincronica.  Necesitas generar el `datatable` dentro de la funcion `complete` del `load()` asi:

```
$(function() { $('#stat').load('ajax/todo.php', function() {
    $('#tabla').DataTable();
}); });
```

Comment: Gracias! entendía un poco lo que pasaba pero no sabia como solucionarlo, gracias de nuevo!